# Ildasm and the Dependency Graph tool in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Can anyone tell me what's the difference between ILDASM tool and the Dependency Graph tool in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate?

Comment: Asking what they have in common would be a more sensible question.

Answer (score 1):

One can show you the disassembled assembly and manifest (ILDASM).

The other will show you the dependencies between classes.

They are totally different tools that do very different things.